# 'ng' is not recognized as a command

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

This question has been posted several times, however, I have not been able to find a solution.

I am using a new computer given to me by my company.
node -v = 14.7.3
npm -v = 6.14.13

npm, node, and Angular's location have been added to %PATH%.

Angular has been installed globally.

I have tried to remove package-lock and node_modules and reinstalling using npm.

I have tried to install/uninstall in the projects root, the projects application folder (where node_modules and package-lock is located, and inside the parent of the project as well just to give it a go.

After all of that, I am still receiving the error. I even tried the old turn it off and back on again trick as well.

I am unsure what to try from here. Any assistance would be great!

I am worried that there is some permission I am missing. In order to do anything on my work computer it feels that I need an admin to come and sign in for me or take control and do it for me.

Please let me know any troubleshooting options I have, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `nvm` (or `nvm for window`)

- they are used to manage node versions
- if you install Angular globally under `nvm` node12, it won't be available on other node versions

Check what node modules are installed globally

- `npm list -g --depth=0`

If global Angular isn't available just run the local projects version

- revert any changes you made to `package.json` and `package-lock.json`
- remove `node_modules`
- `npm install`
- `npm run ng serve -- --port=4200`
- note the extra `--`, as you're passing down params to a sub command

I'd advise against installing Angular globally anyhow. Look up running `angular cli` with `npm run ng` or the equivalent via `npx`

Comment: Ran your command in terminal: " -- @Angular/cli@14.0.2 "